# Issue with fluid, responsive layout and floated elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm designing a basic, two-column fluid responsive layout that linearizes for mobile-- as depicted in my attached diagram[image: responsive layout diagram]-- using floated elements; and I'm having an issue with certain elements dropping, as can be viewed in [the fiddle I've set up here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/chv4jmfq/1/). For some reason, "block 7" aligns with the top of "block 6" instead of flowing below "block 3" as desired.

I have two questions with respect to this layout: (1) how can I get the blocks to align as intended; and (2) is it possible, say using jQuery, to re-arrange the order of blocks for mobile-- for instance, at a certain breakpoint-- I'm using 678px in the fiddle-- I could have, say, "block 6" appear under "block 3"?

For the first question, I have been reading articles and other threads about using `inline-block` instead of `float` although I would prefer to not have to deal with the whitespace issue that seems to occur. If this is the only viable route, however, can it be implemented in a way that minimizes these sorts of quirks? (I've always used floats for layout...)

Thanks very much for any feedback here.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this, I have modified your CSS a little bit:

```css
/*-------------------- clearfix --------------------- */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/*-------------------- main --------------------- */

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 2%;
}
.block {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.two {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.three {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.four {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.seven {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.six {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 200px;
}
.five {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.eight {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
/* 678 breakpoint ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 678px) {
  .block {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container cf">
  <div class="block one">1</div>
  <div class="block two">2</div>
  <div class="block three">3</div>
  <div class="block four">4</div>
  <div class="block five">5</div>
  <div class="block six">6</div>
  <div class="block seven">7</div>
  <div class="block eight">8</div>
</div>
```

First of all, in your original fiddle, the styles which had to be assigned to `.five` div, i.e. `float: left; width: 30%; height: 150px; margin-right: 2%;`, were assigned to `.seven` div and the styles which had to be assigned to `.seven` div, i.e. `float: right; width: 67%; height: 250px;`, were assigned to `.five` div. Moreover, I added `clear: left;` to `.five` div and increased its height.

Secondly, as far changing the order of boxes is concerned at a certain break-point, you can achieve that using CSS only by adding another div of `.six` after `.three` div and hiding it on desktop and showing it only at the break-point, here's an example (view the code snippet in full page and then resize your browser):

```css
/*-------------------- clearfix --------------------- */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
/*-------------------- main --------------------- */

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 2%;
}
.block {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.two {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.three {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.four {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.seven {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 250px;
}
.six {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  height: 200px;
}
.five {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.eight {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.show {
  display: none;
}
/* 678 breakpoint ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 678px) {
  .block {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container cf">
  <div class="block one">1</div>
  <div class="block two">2</div>
  <div class="block three">3</div>
  <div class="block six show">6</div>
  <div class="block four">4</div>
  <div class="block five">5</div>
  <div class="block six hide">6</div>
  <div class="block seven">7</div>
  <div class="block eight">8</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are two instances of the `.six` div in the HTML structure above. First is `<div class="block six show">6</div>` which is after the `.three` div and the other is `<div class="block six hide">6</div>`before the `.seven` div. For the desktop view, I am hiding the first instance of `.six` div by setting `display: none` on `.show` and inside the media-query, I am hiding the second instance of `.six` div by setting `display: none` on `.hude` and showing the first instance of `.six` div by setting `display: block` on `.hide`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Fahad. Something I should have specified, however, is that the layout cannot be dependent on declared heights, as each block will vary in height-- the widths and margins, however, will all be declared as percentages. What I'm trying to avoid is having two main floated columns, containing the blocks as that would create issues with the desired layout for mobile; unless I could somehow remove those containing columns at the specified breakpoint? Hoping this makes sense... EDIT: seeing your updated comment, I would prefer to not duplicate the content if possible; jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but you have to be careful that your right boxes don't exceed the height of the left or it won't tuck under and you may have other alignment problems. Put your content in small viewport order, or the order that it is numbered.

I would suggest, if you want to only have a css way of doing this, using flexbox. It's not fully supported in legacy browsers, but you can have a fallback if you use modernizr. Google "flexbox css" w/o the quotes and there's lots of tutorials.

Edit: I just noticed that 7 is not in the even odd order. I'll leave this for now but will probably delete it tomorrow.

[image]

**DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/aut5haxv/1/**

CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both
}
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.container .column:nth-child(odd) {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.container .column:nth-child(even) {
    width: 68%;
    float: right;
}
.column {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:2%;
}
.one {
    height: 150px
}
.two {
    height: 250px
}
.three {
    height: 250px;
    clear:left;
}
.four {
    height: 450px
}
.five {
    height: 450px;
}
.six {
    height: 350px
}
.seven {
    height: 250px
}
.eight {
    height: 200px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:678px) { 
    .container .column:nth-child(odd),
    .container .column:nth-child(even) {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="column one">1</div>
   <div class="column two">2</div>
   <div class="column three">3</div>
   <div class="column four">4</div>
   <div class="column five">5</div>  
   <div class="column six">6</div> 
   <div class="column seven">7</div>
   <div class="column eight">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Christina! This is interesting-- the only thing I would have to modify is the odd/even declarations, as I intend to have multiple, successive floated elements on the right-- i.e. w/ the wider width. Is it the `border-box` property that is helping here? Also, I have contemplated the flexbox route, but my concern for this project in particular is that many visitors will be using older browsers, thus necessitating an adequate fallback/polyfill...

Comment: box-sizing:border-box calculates the padding and the border so that you can use percentages. I wouldn't bother with this as it's fickle for unknown heights... a box will be taller when it's narrower. Instead I would use a regular, fluid layout for desktop devices and then in my CMS, use server side sniffing (php-mobile-detect for example) and then show the html in the order you want for small devices.

Comment: .no-flexbox I believe is the html class that modernizer uses. Older browsers would see the order of the html as it is and modern browsers would see the order you assigned using flexbox.