# Rearrange layout blocks with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I started a separate thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642933/issue-with-fluid-responsive-layout-and-floated-elements) regarding a different approach in constructing a fully fluid, responsive layout using floats, and I'm thinking an entirely different solution might be in order. [I have started a new fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/dtxLrujn/5/), in which I've separated the layout blocks into two main columns, i.e. `.left-column` and `.right-column`. I'm wondering if, via jQuery, I can essentially remove these column containers at a certain breakpoint--say @ 678px-- force all the divs to linearize @ 100% width, and rearrange them such that, in this mockup, they are ordered sequentially from 1 to 8.

Can this be easily achieved with jQuery? Also, I'm open to any other (e.g. css-only) suggestions as far as achieving this desired effect. I'm finding that floating all the elements as presented in my other attempt is proving too problematic (at least in my current implementation.)

Thanks much for any assistance here.

Comment: Did you check http://masonjs.com/ or similar libs.

Comment: Wow, I had tried jQuery masonry and found the behavior too erractic, but hadn't heard of mason; have you found it easy to work with?

Comment: Your case is rather simple. Both should work for you. There is always more to try http://jquery-plugins.net/category/grid-layout

Comment: @cforcloud: would you mind taking a look at my mockup using mason here: http://tinyurl.com/q2d9tjo  Clearly I'm doing something wrong here; I'm a bit confused regarding the "ratio" and "sizes" options; really all I'm going for is the blocks aligning vertically without any extra space in between; I would like to define all widths/heights in CSS.

Comment: I just discovered freetile.js which seems to work well (thus far) minus the headaches I encountered with masonry...

Comment: Oh, didnt solutions in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642933/issue-with-fluid-responsive-layout-and-floated-elements) solve your issue. may i know why?

Comment: @cforcloud: while helpful, the suggested approaches relied on the heights being declared for the various blocks, and this is not feasible for the project in question-- I should have specified that point in the question-- and I'm not quite comfortable with the current level of support for flexbox-- which is ultimately the best solution. So I'm going back to a script-based approach, and freetile.js seems to be the best I found thus far for my specific requirements (masonry and the like have caused nothing but headaches when dealing with percentage-based widths and needing to specify columns...)

Comment: [flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) is now supported in most major browsers, but I think it wont solve our problem. 
1. Does the item heights dynamically vary, like expand-collapse at times
2. freetilejs doesn't seems to use columns to align, heights are fixed as well
3. test [wookmarkjs](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin)
4. like in your fiddle is it two/multi columned or tiled based alignment?

Answer (score 1):

One more column based grid solution with the help of [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).
Here you can adjust the column widths by using the [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/cforcloud/qmaagw3r/) if you want to play with.

```js
$(function(){

$.fn.itemify = function(update){

var $t = $(this);

if ($t.data('itemify') && update!==true) return this;

var options = { col:'.col', item:'.item' },

items = $t.find(options.item),
col_count = 0,

fn = function(){
  var cols = $t.find(options.col+':visible');
  if( cols.length == col_count ) return;
  
  console.log(cols.length, col_count);
  col_count = cols.length;
  
  $t.find(options.col).empty();
  
  items.each(function(i, t){
   shortest(cols).append(t);
  });
},

shortest = function(cols){
var a = 0, h = -1;
cols.each(function(i,t){
   if( $(t).height() < h || h==-1 ) {
      h = $(t).height();
      a = i;
   }
   //console.log( a, b, h, $(this).height() );
});
return cols.eq(a);
};

$(window).unbind('resize', fn).bind('resize', fn);
fn();

return this.data('itemify', 1);
};


/* ----- testing - START item + window resizing --*/
var test_items = $('#itemify .item');
$('.test').removeClass('hide').find('button').click(function(){
  var col = $('#itemify .col').eq(0).append(test_items), len = $('#itemify .item').length;
  
  for( i=0; i<10; i++)
    col.append( $('<div class="item">'+ ++len +'</div>').height( Math.random()*300+20 ) );
  
  test_items = $('#itemify .item');
  test();
  $('#itemify').itemify(true);
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 100);
});
function test(){
 $('.test .txt').text($('#itemify .item').length + ' items');
 
 $('#itemify .item').each(function(){
  var $t = $(this);
  
  if( $t.find('textarea').length==0 ) {
    $t.html( $('<textarea>'+ $t.text() +'</textarea>').height( $t.height()-5 ) );
    $t.removeAttr('style').removeClass().addClass('item');
  }
 });
}
test();
/* ----- testing - END -- */


/// start itemify
$('#itemify').itemify();

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.row#itemify {
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}
.row .col {
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
.item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.one {
  height: 170px;
}
.two {
  height: 250px;
}
.three {
  height: 150px;
}
.four {
  height: 250px;
}
.five {
  height: 450px;
}
.six {
  height: 350px;
}
.seven {
  height: 250px;
}
.eight {
  height: 200px;
}
.nine {
  height: 500px;
}

/* testing */
.test {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 80%;
}
.item textarea {
  border: medium none;
  resize: vertical;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="itemify" class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="item one">1</div>
      <div class="item two">2</div>
      <div class="item three">3</div>
      <div class="item four">4</div>
      <div class="item five">5</div>
      <div class="item six">6</div>
      <div class="item seven">7</div>
      <div class="item eight">8</div>
      <div class="item nine">9</div>
      <div class="item five">10</div>
      
      <!-- more items -->
      <div class="item six">11</div>
      <div class="item two">12</div>
      <div class="item four">13</div>
      <div class="item eight">14</div>
      <div class="item three">15</div>
      <div class="item one">16</div>
      <div class="item nine">17</div>
      <div class="item seven">18</div>
      <div class="item two">19</div>
      <div class="item eight">20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-2 visible-sm visible-md visible-lg"></div>
    <div class="col col-md-5 col-lg-3 visible-md visible-lg"></div>
    <div class="col col-lg-5 visible-lg"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- testing -->
<div class="test hide">
  <div class="txt">txt</div>
  <button>add 10 items</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks cforcloud, this is a really interesting solution; probably the best I've seen thus far. I was experimenting with freetile.js as a possible solution, but I'm still experiencing some erratic behavior similar to that with masonry-- if you'd be so kind as to check out my test page [here](http://nickpish.com/_dev/freetile/)-- and see if you have any ideas as to what's going on, I'd be most appreciative. I like the simplicity of this approach, but I'm still experiencing the elements dropping into a single column; however, upon resizing the browser window the divs will align properly (?)

Comment: @nickpish i guess that is how it works. you could log your [issue to freetile](https://github.com/yconst/Freetile/issues). i just [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cforcloud/qmaagw3r/9/).